# How frequently do Federation Starfleet personnel receive shore leave?

Tags: star-trek, federation

According to the [Memory Alpha page on shore leave](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Shore_leave), Starfleet (both Earth and Federation) receive occasional shore leave.  One thing the page doesn't mention though is the frequency of shore leave.  I'd like to know how frequently shore leave is granted for example in a formula i.e. after 'x' months of duty officers receive 'y' weeks of leave.  All I could find from the aforementioned Memory Alpha page was:

> by the time of the Ba'ku incident, Picard was owed a staggering amount of shore leave: 318 days, to be exact

I imagine some calculations could be done based on the above number, but taking into account that Picard did have some terms of shore leave on Risa (*Captain's Holiday*) and Earth (*Family*), we don't know prior to TNG when Picard had last had shore leave!

I would prefer some sort of evidence which explains the frequency of shore leave (or for that matter if it is granted purely based on how well the crew is coping at any one time, although I doubt that would be the sole reason, as the number of days Picard was owed suggests a more precise system).

Answer (score 6):

Any organization like Starfleet will have what you said: "after 'x' months of duty officers receive 'y' weeks of leave" with y usually increasing with rank.

In-universe, there is a formula somewhere.

On screen, the formula is so low-level it is highly unlikely you will ever see it in canon. Maybe in a c-grade fanfic with a print run easily handled by my inkjet.

In reality, if the plot *requires* someone to take leave, their owed-leave level is simply cranked up to the point where being ordered to take a vacation is not unreasonable. There is mention somewhere of "take a vaction, or I will have you loaded into a torpedo casing and fire you down there myself"

Personally, I'd take holodeck credits over shore leave.

Comment: Re that last comment, being on the holodeck on your ship/starbase might be fun, but you're always within easy calling distance of work. Several days or weeks in a different environment allows you to let your work go. Your deputies have to take care of things, for better or worse. A holosuite on Risa, now that would be something ...

Comment: If you have a holodeck, you don't need Risa. If you are on Risa, you prb. don't need a holodeck.

Comment: @paul - i also support you.. holodeck for me as well, in incognito / privacy - ON mode :D